# Why is the variable nil even if I don't set it to nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I don't understand why `current_user` is nil after deleting `user_id` from `session`. When the `current_user` function is called wouldn't it return the old `current_user` value again?

```
#Returns the current logged-in user (if any).
def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
end

# Logs out the current user.
def log_out
    session.delete(:user_id)
    # @current_user = nil
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume these methods are defined in a controller.  Controller instance variables only have a lifespan of a single HTTP request.  Session values last longer, but you've deleted the session value that matters here.

When the next request comes in, `@current_user` needs to be set again, and since  `session[:user_id]` is nil, you are essentially calling `User.find_by(id: nil)`, which will return nil.